# Use different template for same route based on user group

Tags: routes

I'd like to have consistent URL's for an account section but depending on the current users group, the template will be different. I know I could use the same template but there would be a lot of if/else's throughout and I'd like to avoid that.

URL pattern would be something like this:

If customer group
`'account/settings' => '_dashboard/customer/settings'`

If admin group
`'account/settings' => '_dashboard/admin/settings'`

I was thinking this might be possible with a plugin controller that each route would hit and then decide which template to render.

For both groups
`'account/settings' => ['action' => 'action/path']`

```
function action()
{
   // Get user
   // Set path based on user group
   // Set template path to front end
   // Render template
}
```

Can you see any problems with the above solution? Will there be much of a performance hit? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it with Twig by having a main template pull from two other templates based on the user group. So in your index template (or whatever template gets called), just add this at the top:

```
{% if currentUser.isInGroup('customer') %}
    {% include '_dashboard/customer/settings' %}
{% else %}
    {% include '_dashboard/admin/settings' %}
{% endif %}
```

And then fill out each template however you want.

Conversely, you can check if the user is a CMS admin with `{% if currentUser.admin %}` and then the `{% else %}` would be for customers.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. This is a good option, however it does mean creating extra templates. Will wait to see if anyone else has any ideas before marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: It only adds 1 extra template: the index. It would be better to direct to `dashboard/index` and then have two templates in `dashboard/` called `_customerSettings` and `_adminSettings`.  Going your route with the controller still utilizes multiple templates.  And in addition, my way also allows you to use the index as a global template to set things the other two share so you don't repeat yourself.